# HTTPS WCF Basic HttpBindings getting HTTP 403

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

I have an HTTPS webserver on WCF hosted under IIS 7.5. I have set the SSL settings to require SSL and ignore client certificates.

When I try to add the web reference in Visual Studio, I get the following error. How do I fix this problem?

I can see that it's trying to request `?disco` using HTTP instead of HTTPS. I think this is the problem, but I am not sure how to address this.

> The document at the url https://testserver/service1.svc?wsdl was not recognized as a known document type.
>   The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'http://testserver/service1.svc?disco'.'.
>     - The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
>   - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
>   - Report from 'https://testserver/service1.svc?wsdl' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.

Comment: When you try to browse the url in your web browser https://testserver/service1.svc?wsdl  what do you get?

Comment: I do not receive any error i get to the page. i have the cert trusted on my root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to disable *Require SSL* to get it to work. I am not sure why disco goes to do an HTTP when the WSDL URL you provide is HTTPS.

Comment: How do you disable require ssl? The config seems to just have httpsGetEnabled and httpGetEnabled.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're able to get the WSDL through your web browser, a possible issue might be with hosting the service in IIS and configuring site bindings. It was a known issue on the forums some time ago, check out these links:

- [Problem in consuming hosted WCF service](http://forums.asp.net/t/1491756.aspx/1)
- [HOWTO: Fix WCF Host Name on IIS](http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis/)

Good luck!